# T SQL casting to Int by default

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

So, this:

```
select ceiling(5/4)
```

Is not the same as this:

```
select ceiling(1.25)
```

The fraction evaluates to 1, the decimal evaluates to 2.  This seems incredibly stupid to me.  How can I get SSMS to play nice?

Comment: The rules for constant data types are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx). You can use `CAST` or `CONVERT` to change the data type of an expression. Note that, due to the rules of [data type precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), that if either value is a `float` then the expression will be a `float`, e.g. `5 / 4.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 and 4 are typed ints implicitly. You could write them as 5.0 and 4.0 instead, e.g:

```
select ceiling(5.0/4.0)
```

result: 2

Comment: That's extremely unintuitive, but it works, thank you.